# Batch - replacing with percent symbol

Tags: string, batch-file, symbols

I want to replace "mod" in string with "%":
`set string=%string:mod=x%`
What I should input as "x"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do that by enabling delayed expansion so you can use `!` as delimiters. Then, doubling the percent sign allows to represent percent as a replacement char.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set string=12 mod 15
set string=!string:mod=%%!
echo %string%
```

result

```
12 % 15
```