# Managing special characters in batch script to write WinSCP "open" connection string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sftp, winscp

I'm trying write the batch code to generate a script into a file, to open a connection with WinSCP; the final command should be like:

```
open sftp://user:password@example.com/
```

The password contains the `+` symbol and I must change it into `%2B` to make WinSCP understand.

```
set pw=mypassword+
::echo %pw% return--> mypassword+
set st=%%2B
::echo %st% return--> &2B
call set pw=%%pw:+=%st%%%
::echo %pw% return--> mypassword2B
```

I can't find the way to make last call to return `%pw%=mypassword%2B` (with `%` before `2B`) to pass to WinSCP script. Can you help me, please? Or is there another strategy (but always in batch file) to make WinSCP `open` command accept the correct password? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set pw=!pw:+=%%2B!
```

Note that you have to remove the `call`.

Based on [Batch - replacing with percent symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41323488/850848).

---

Also, there's an alternative way to provide the password to WinSCP, using [`-password` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#password).

```
open ftp://username@ftp.example.com/ -password="mypassword+"
```

*You need WinSCP 5.19 for this.*

Comment: Great! The first way work perfectly; I'll try the alternative for winscp as soon as I can. Thanks a lot!